# Does Sabre Air Availability get more than 7 seats?

Tags: sabre

I'm using OTA_AirAvailLLSRQ API to search flights, but it only shows 7 seats each class. I wonder is there any way or function in Sabre can show total available seats of each class.

I am brand new to Sabre and appreciate any advice on if this kind of data is possible or available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because LLSR service support is very limited, I would recommend looking for a newer service that allows you to retrieve all information, such as Bargain Finder Max, along the Seats Rest service which retrieves the complete seat maps for all cabins.

Best regards.